# I have 500 Internal Server Error in Component Manager

Tags: magento2, error, http-error-500, component-manager

Magento 2. When I try to open Component Manager I get a `500 Internal Server Error` on

`/setup/index.php/componentGrid/components`

and the page does not load. 
[image]

I am using php 5.6

[image]

Comment: 500 error means some errors inside PHP most of the time. Please check `var/log/exception.log` and post the related error messages first(if any).

Comment: I haven't any logs about this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by following below steps:

- Open `/setup/index.php/componentGrid/components` in new tab
- It showed me an actual error, in my case, it was the last extension installed through composer.
- I have removed that from composer
- After updating composer, I have to execute following commands as well.
- `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was a language package called `magento2translations/language_es_es` downloaded outside of Magento marketplace.

You need to open http://your.domain.com/setup/index.php/componentGrid/components

and see which package is causing the problem, then remove all reference to this package in `composer.json` and `composer.lock` then you are DONE!

I am using Magento 2.1.7