# Component Manager keeps on loading after System Upgrade

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions, magento2.1.6, component, component-manager

I did system upgrade from **Magento ver. 2.0.7** to **Magento ver. 2.1.6** by admin panel.

I clean the cache but the component manager keeps on loading.

There's an error on my console:

```
Failed to /setup/index.php/componentGrid/components load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

How to fix this one?

Comment: have you ran setup upgrade command after upgrade?

Comment: @Sarfarazbheda Do I still need to run the upgrade command  if the cron is running? But yes, I did.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4546

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by executing below steps:

- Open /setup/index.php/componentGrid/components in new tab
- It showed me the actual error, in my case, it was the last extension installed through composer.
- I have removed that from the composer
- After updating the composer, I have to execute the following commands as well.
- `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/182945/56221